# how to extract multiple ROI and save it with desire .jpg folder names in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

i have a question regarding this thread [similiar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104664/extract-all-bounding-boxes-using-opencv-python/25912437?noredirect=1#comment40561635_25912437), and iam having a similiar problem, my problem is i want to extract the ROI's with desire names, so i can call it anytime. cause now iam building a OCR program with template matching.what i got so far are that i can extract all those ROI's but i also got a random .jpg file names.

```
cv2.imwrite()
```

Comment: How are you storing the values of multiple Rectangles & how you are drawing them?

Comment: iam using [y:y+h,x:x+w], i drawing them with cv2.rectangle().all i want that all cropped ROI's that i save have name in order like ex : a-z etc. you can see in the "similiar code"

Comment: i mean how are you looping through all the rectangles stored?

Comment: from the "similiar problem" i used idx+=1, but i still dont know how exactly