# I am trying to export the bounding boxes and save them to a file to utilize later in object classification. Using Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tensorflow2

[Tree with leaf detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxmqQ.jpg)

I have tried several solutions but all tend to just pull either numbers or grey and black. [This is one of the solutions I have tried.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104664/extract-all-bounding-boxes-using-opencv-python/21108680) [Here is the second set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104664/extract-all-bounding-boxes-using-opencv-python)

```
# Test image Directory
 image_dir = 'C:/Users/tbrau/Documents/SeniorProject/TensorFlow/workspace/training_demo-
 /images/test/LeafType1Test'

elapsed = []
for i in range(5):
   image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, 'out' + str(i + 1) + '.jpg')
   image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
   input_tensor = np.expand_dims(image_np, 0)
   start_time = time.time()
   detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
   end_time = time.time()
   elapsed.append(end_time - start_time)


plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [100, 100]
label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()
viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image_np_with_detections,
    detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
    detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(np.int32),
    detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    max_boxes_to_draw=200,
    min_score_thresh=.40,
    agnostic_mode=False)
 plt.imsave(str(i) + '.jpg', image_np_with_detections)   
 plt.subplot(5, 1, i+1)
 plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
 plt.savefig('LeafType1.jpg')
mean_elapsed = sum(elapsed) / float(len(elapsed))
print('Elapsed time: ' + str(mean_elapsed) + ' second per image')
```